# Finding number of occurence of a specific string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Consider the string `"55,33,255,66,55"`

I am finding ways to count number of occurence of a specific characters ("55" in this case) in this string using mysql select query.

Currently i am using the below logic to count

```
 
select CAST((LENGTH("55,33,255,66,55") - LENGTH(REPLACE("55,33,255,66,55", "55", ""))) / LENGTH("55") AS UNSIGNED)
```

But the issue with this one is, it counts all occurence of 55 and the **result is = 3**,
but the desired output is = 2.

Is there any way i can make this work correct? please suggest.

**NOTE : "55" is the input we are giving and consider the value "55,33,255,66,55" is from a database field.**

Regards,

Balan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to match on `',55,'`, but there's the first and last position to worry about. You can use the trick of adding commas to the frot and back of the input to get around that:

```
select LENGTH('55,33,255,66,55') + 2 -
    LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', '55,33,255,66,55', ','), ',55,', 'xxx'))
```

Returns `2`

I've used `CONCAT` to pre- and post-pend the commas (rather than adding a literal into the text) because I assume you'll be using this on a column not a literal.

Note also these improvements:

- Removal of the cast - it is already numeric
- By replacing with a string one less in length (ie `',55,'` length 4 to `'xxx'` length 3), the result doesn't need to be divided - it's already the correct result
- `2` is added to the length because of the two commas added front and back (no need to use `CONCAT` to calculate the pre-replace length)

Answer (score 0):

I would do an sub select in this sub select I would replace every 255 with some other unique signs and them count the new signs and the standing 55's.

```
If(row = '255') then '1337'
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CAST((LENGTH("55,33,255,66,55") + 2 - LENGTH(REPLACE(concat(",","55,33,255,66,55",","), ",55,", ",,"))) / LENGTH("55") AS UNSIGNED)
```